# struts2 - value cannot return in result of s:action tag

Tags: java, struts2

I need a help in struts `<s:action>` tag.
In my code i want to show a phone number dynamically in my jsp page, I wrote in jsp as

```
<s:action name="getPhone" executeResult="true"/>
```

i only need to return the phone number variable only. So is there any way to display the phone number without use a resulting new jsp.

Comment: Yes there is. But why do you need to call an action in jsp? Why don't you do it on action call not from jsp?

Comment: Why is this a separate action?

Comment: Clarify how do you want to show a phone number dynamically.

Comment: phone number shows at the footer of the page. So i wrote my <s:action> tag on the footer.jsp file to get the phone number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it maybe not the best solution to your issue, because it is usually not the best case to execute an action from JSP using `<s:action>` tag. But you can use `var` attribute of `<s:action>` tag to assign name to the value pushed into the value stack which can be used later to get property of this action. And you don't need to execute result so set `executeResult` attribute to `false`.

```
<s:action var="phoneAction" name="getPhone" executeResult="false" />
<s:property value="#phoneAction.phoneField" />
```

Comment: executeResult is false by default so removing it is enough :)

Comment: Explicitly set it to false won't hurt ;) Little future-proof precaution.